# Why is it when I push a variable onto my vector it's not pushing the value I expect?

Tags: c++

I'm writing a function that will be able to find a path between two locations. I believe that the function can find a path since it is returning true when it finds the destination, my problem is that when I push the destination onto the vector and print it to my out-file, it is not pushing the location that I need, although when I print it to the console it prints what I expect it to print.

I've tried writing multiple lines to push the same variable onto the vector, and each time it pushes a different location onto it, although whenever I print it to the console it still prints what I expect. I've also tried simply pushing the exact data I need onto the vector, and it still does not print to the out-file what I expect it to.

```
bool findShortestPath(vector<int> & visitedNodes, vector<int> & shortestPath, int & startNode, int & endNode, string mode)
{

    visitedNodes.push_back(startNode);
    shortestPath.push_back(startNode);

    vector<int> neighbours;
    Link thisLink(0, 0, "");
    neighbours = findNeighbours(startNode);



    if (startNode == endNode)
    {
        cout << startNode << endl;
        shortestPath.push_back(startNode);
        cout << "hello" << endl << endl;
        return true;
    }


    else
    {


        for (int neighbour : neighbours)
        {
            for (Link link : links)
            {
                if (link.getRef1() == startNode && link.getRef2() == neighbour)
                {
                    thisLink = link;
                    break;
                }
                else if (link.getRef2() == startNode && link.getRef1() == neighbour)
                {
                    thisLink = link;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (std::find(visitedNodes.begin(), visitedNodes.end(), neighbour) == visitedNodes.end() || visitedNodes.empty())
            {
                if (thisLink.checkMode(mode))
                {
                    findShortestPath(visitedNodes, shortestPath, neighbour, endNode, mode);
                }
            }           

        }
        shortestPath.pop_back();
        cout << "Bye" << endl;
        return false;
    }




}
```

Where the function is called...

```
        else if (command == "FindRoute")
        {
            vector<int> path;
            stringstream stream(commandString);
            string splitString; 
            string output;
            string mode;
            int startNode;
            int endNode;
            int i = 0;

            while (getline(stream, splitString, ' '))
            {
                if (i == 1)
                {
                    mode = splitString;
                }
                else if (i == 2)
                {
                    stringstream startNodeString(splitString);
                    startNodeString >> startNode;
                }
                else if (i == 3)
                {
                    stringstream endNodeString(splitString);
                    endNodeString >> endNode;
                }
                i++;
            }
            vector<int> visitedNodes;


                findShortestPath(visitedNodes, path, startNode, endNode, mode);

                for (int node : path)
                {
                    _outFile << node << endl;
                }


            return true;
        }
```

I've stepped through the code, and startNode is exactly what I expect it to be when it get's pushed onto shortestPath.
So the input is "FindRoute Rail 9081958 15832241" So it's looking for a route between the locations 9081958 and 15832241. When I use cout << node << endl; it comes out with 9081958 9361783. The same as the write-to-file.

Comment: This is not clear. Where is the non-working write-to-file code?

Comment: Edited to include where it's being written to the file.

Comment: And if you use cout << node << endl; instead of _outFile << node << endl;, you get different output?

Comment: So the input is "FindRoute Rail 9081958 15832241" So it's looking for a route between the locations 9081958 and 15832241. When I use cout << node << endl; it comes out with 9081958 9361783. The same as the write-to-file.

Comment: Because the function is returning true, I'm expecting the second node to be 15832241

Comment: I've now changed "shortestPath.pop_back();" to "shortestPath.erase(std::find(shortestPath.begin(), shortestPath.end(), startNode));" because I thought that maybe pop_back was taking away nodes that I wanted because of when it's going to be called.

Comment: I'm afraid it's really not at all clear what the problem is. Put in a single code fragment, no multiple, and put in comments at key points explaining what you're expecting and what you're getting.